# How to set up subscription service with credits that visitors can use to buy products?

Tags: commerce

I have a client that has a Drupal 7 site with Drupal Commerce already running to manage his store of products.

He wants to add a subscription service where users could pay a monthly subscription fee, and this fee would give them credits to buy products with.

Just wondering the best way to set this up/what recommendations people have to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

The Drupal Commerce site builder's guide [refers to](https://drupalcommerce.org/site-builders-guide/store-credit) modules named [Commerce Credits](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_credits) and [Commerce Credits Transactions](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_credits_transaction) for building sites with a "store credit" feature.

However, these modules seem to be unmaintained and aren't covered by Drupal.org security policies, so you would need to evaluate the value of using them in your integration vs the risk of having to support a site using them without much help.